# What Happens to a weak_ptr when Its shared_ptr is Destroyed?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

It seems that a [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) somehow just knows when the [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) it references has been destroyed. How is that? Is there a constant link maintained or something?

Take the [following code for example](http://ideone.com/Jveo4K):

```
weak_ptr<int> test() {
    shared_ptr<int> foo{new int};

    return foo;
}

int main() {
    auto foo = test();

    cout << foo.expired() << endl;
}
```

I would have expected a segfault when the `weak_ptr<int>` goes to check on the state of the `shared_ptr<int>` but there isn't one. The `weak_ptr<int>` correctly identifies the memory as deallocated. How does it know?

Comment: 'std::weak_ptr' holds a reference to a shared reference count the same way 'std::shared_ptr' does. Only difference is that 'std::weak_ptr' does not increment/decrement this count.

Comment: *I would have expected a segfault...* Why? that's specifically the point of weak_ptr

Comment: @UmNyobe Good point! I guess I was trying to communicate that I didn't understand how it worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr` is created using two pieces of memory:

- A resource block: This holds the pointer to the actual underlying data, e.g. 'int*'
- A control block: This holds information specific to a shared_ptr, for example reference counts.

(Sometimes these are allocated in a single chunk of memory for efficiency, see `std::make_shared`)

The **control block** *also* stores reference counts for `weak_ptr`. It will not be deallocated until the last `weak_ptr` goes out of scope (the weak pointer reference count drops to zero).

So a `weak_ptr` will know that it's expired because it has access to this control block, and it can check to see what the reference count is for a `shared_ptr`

Comment: I'm having a misunderstanding here. So you're saying that the **control block** actually stores 2 counts? The number of `weak_ptr`s and the number of `shared_ptr`s? And it isn't destroyed till BOTH are 0?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Yes, conceptually that's what's happening. By the way, you can open your standard library header files and look at the implementation yourself!

Comment: @AndyG No idea. I just completely didn't understand how `weak_ptr`s worked. Thanks for the explanation! I'll accept shortly.

Comment: @JonathanMee: And a corollary is that, when you use `make_shared` to allocate both in a single block of memory, that memory floats around until all your `weak_ptrs` also go out of scope.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only possible implementation, and the Standard generally describes only the interface.